# Display Post if ACF Page Link Matches Current Page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm setting up a system to show customer reviews on a Wordpress site. We have 6 service pages and I want to be able to choose when creating the review which of the service pages it shows on. I only want one random review that matches the relevant page to show each time.

I've created a custom post type ('review'), added fields for review text, reviewer name, etc. I've also added an ACF Page Link field which allows me to choose the page or pages I want the review to show on. This is where I'm a bit stuck. I basically want the query to only get posts that match the Page Link selection. I can make it do the comparison later during the loop quite easily, but I can't work out how to set the arguments to filter down in this way.

This is what I currently have:

```
global $post;
    $args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'review',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
        );
        
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        
        echo '<div class="review-block">';
    
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        
            $page_to_display_on = get_field ('page_to_display_on');
            $reviewer_name = get_field ('reviewer_name');
            $service_supplied = get_field ('service_supplied');
            $reviewer_image = get_field ('reviewer_image');
            $review_text = get_field ('review_text');
            $review_stars = get_field ('review_stars');

echo $current_url;
            echo '<div class="review-image">';
            if ( $reviewer_image ) {
                echo '<img class="review-image-circle" src="' . $reviewer_image . '" />';
            }
            else {
                echo '<img class="review-image-circle" src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/google-reviews-icon.png" />';
            }
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="review-content">';
            echo '<p>' . $review_text . '</p>';
            echo '<p class="review-name">' . $reviewer_name . ' - ' . $service_supplied . '</p>';
           
            for($x=1;$x<=$review_stars;$x++) {
                echo '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
            }
            if (strpos($review_stars,'.')) {
                echo '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                $x++;
            }
            while ($x<=5) {
                echo '<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                $x++;
            }
            

            echo '</div>';
           

        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Is there a way to do a relationship query with an ACF custom field? Would I be better using a 'Post Object' field in ACF, which can return the post ID instead?

Comment: Their documentation has an article [How to Query Posts by Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/), have you looked through that already?

Comment: _"Would I be better using a 'Post Object' field in ACF, which can return the post ID instead?"_ - in principle, it shouldn't matter _what_ value you filter by, it works the same either way. If you don't _need_ to explicitly store a page link, I would probably go with just the ID though. Via the global $post, you have access to the ID on every page already, whereas the "page link" of the current page is something you would need to get first.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the pointers. I just added this to the query:
    `'meta_key' => 'page_to_display_on',
    'meta_value' => $post->ID`
And it worked!